# Fastest way to cut and remove parts of a video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, adobe-premiere

I have a movie which is encoded using H264 (mp4) and is 800 MB in 720p format.
I need to remove some parts of it for example remove 10:25 to 10:30 and so on.
I've worked with adobe premiere buy it gets too much time and energy (laptop's fan run high and goes hot) cause it decodes and re-encodes video.
I dont know much about internals of video editing but is there any better or faster way for this kind of works? Maybe better tool or better settings (i use default settings for output in premiere). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way is to use lower quality, better tool!? if you mean different app try Movie maker, if you want something light on your laptop, small app easy and fast, give it a try

Comment: @narzan I think if I wanted to convert it to lower quality it takes longer! I dont think that Movie Maker is a good option since it exports to wmv, which makes me needing a software for wmv to mp4 conversion, which increases the spent time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible that your software is re-encoding the file.  If you just want to *copy* a 5 second chunk of the movie, you can use this command:

`ffmpeg -i YourFile.mp4 -ss 00:10:25 -t 00:00:05 -acodec copy -vcodec copy Output.mp4`

- Where `-i` is the name of your file.
- `-ss` is the start position in Hours:Minutes:Seconds
- `-t` is how long a clip you want - again in HH:MM:SS
- The `acodec` and `vcodec` tells `ffmpeg` just to *copy* the file without changing it at all.

That's about the fastest you can get it.

Comment: yeah as it seems it is. but how can I remove 5 seconds of a video (in the middle) ? should I do 3 works? (getting start to somewhere; getting somewhere+5 to end; join these 2) or there is a straight way ?

Comment: You'll have to do it as three separate actions, sorry.

Comment: could you give me the joining command? assume that I run that command twice and I have `firstoutput.mp4` and `secondoutput.mp4` files. what command should I use to join these two?

Comment: @TechJS, FWIW, I've had good luck using the `cat` command to join video snippets that are in the `.mpg` container.

Comment: @Digger Thanks for mentioning. I'll give it a try as soon as I come back to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

[avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) can perform cutting for any kind of file. You'll obviously only be able to cut H.264 streams on keyframes, but that's the best you'll be able to get.